# convert incoming message to parquet format

Tags: apache-nifi

I know I can read from nifi using spark and write to hdfs in parquet format, but is there a way directly from apache-nifi to write to HDFS in parquet format ?.Please advice

Thanks 
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [PutParquet](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-parquet-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.PutParquet/index.html) processor in NiFi.
You will have to provide schema for the incoming flowfile in avro schema format and specify the HDFS directory the converted parquet file should be saved to. You can find detailed example [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/140422/convert-data-from-jsoncsvavro-to-parquet-with-nifi.html).

Comment: Please insert an example. Link-only answers are to be avoided.